# javascript or jquery: find out weather a page have openned with internet explorer object or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

our company has a website with so many pages and some of these pages can be open with internet explorer object inside our desktop application.
I'm wondering if there any way to find out whether a page is opened with external browser or with the IE object?

Note that we want to detect this with some code inside our pages aad also we want to seperate ie object requests from external IE request.

Comment: In javascript you can use navigator.userAgent to identify your browser. It might be worth checking if the IE Object uses another user agent than the IE browser.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: @Priyank: but i want to seperate ie object requests from external IE. how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check using `$.browser.msie` to detect if the page is opened with internet explorer. This will return `true` when the page will be opened using internet explorer and then you can perform your task.